# How to calculate coordinate of a selected points in QGIS?

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude

How to calculate coordinate of a selected points in QGIS? Not just x, y, I need like this: `X = 77° 1' 5.032" E Y = 28° 38' 58.034" N`.

Refer the attached image the (x,y,z) columns coordinate generated in QGIS but the
(COORDI) column is generated in ArcGIS. this (COORDI) column how I get in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?